# Get variable from MainActivity in OnHandleIntent

Tags: android

I´m pretty new in android. I have made communication between two Apps with BroadcastReceiver and intentServices .
The thing is, I want to send information to the app2 from app1. In app1 I need to access a variable which is in MainActivity.class , I need to send it to servicev.class (the service where the intent is handled) but the variable "res" is null when I access it, why does that happen? (App2 calls app1 onHandleIntent and it breaks in res.getOtp() )  I try to create an extra setter getter class and also an intent but getIntent() does not work inside onHandleIntent... how can I achieve to pass res.getOTP (string) ? I really dont want to use SQLite

servicev:

```
public class servicev extends IntentService {
    private static final int RESULT_OK = 1;
    protected ResultReceiver mReceiver;


    public servicev() {

        super("yeah");


    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

//I receive here the intent from app2 and I need to response with res.getOTP()

helper h = new helper();   

        String val = intent.getStringExtra("foo");
        Intent in = new Intent("com.banorte.bem.movil.veriToken.SendBroadcast");
        in.putExtra("resultCode", this.RESULT_OK);
        in.putExtra("resultValue", "My Result Value. Passed in: " + h.getRes().getOtp());    //h here is null... setter and getter approach does not work... maybe sqlite could work but it is necesary?

        sendBroadcast(in);
    }


}
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {




    VTTokenAPI api;
    TextView textView;
    Button button;
    EditText input;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        AndroidSetup.getInstance().init(this);
helper h = new helper();
        api = new VTTokenAPI("FFFFFF");
        res = api.getStatus();

        res.getOtp();   //correct value
h.setRes(res);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }


}
```

helper:

```
public class helper {

 public VTResult getRes() {
            return res;
        }

        public void setRes(VTResult res) {
            this.res = res;
        }

        VTResult res;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to instantiate a new `MainActivity` which is not the same as the running activity but a new instance.

If you need your `IntentService` to be able to get data from a running `Activity` you have options such as using `SharedPreferences` or SQLite. Instead of keeping the data in memory try to persist it in some database in the `onCreate` and then try to read it from the storage during `handleIntent`

Comment: SharedPreferences I will take a look on that....  the instance of MainActivity is a mistake but taht was my last attempt

Comment: In that case unless `res` is static you would have the same problem. Try declaring it as `static VTResult res`. However this is not a good design as your application might restart and in some cases you can lose data. Using persistent storage is a better design.

Comment: In the mean time ill use static